# Buttons on UIView semitransparent are not visible

Tags: uiview, uibutton, subview, alpha

I have a UIView with some parts semi-transparent (alpha <1.0) and other opaque. I want to put buttons opaque as subview and I noticed that the parts they become translucent buttons also, while in other parts of the opaque buttons you can not see even if set with alpha = 1.0.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  //......
  self.viewSito = [[UIView alloc]init];
  //this view has some parts semi-trasparent and other opaque

  self.buttonClose =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  self.buttonClose.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
  self.buttonClose.alpha =1.0;
 /*the output is semi-transparent when is on uiview semi-transparent, but when uiview is 
  opaque the button is not visible, as if it were "hidden" from the opaque part 
  of the view.*/
  //...

 [self.viewSito addSubview:self.buttonClose];

}
```

The button still works, it's just a problem of visibility.What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set your UIView  semi-trasparent in this way:

myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1f green:.1f blue:.1f alpha:.7f];

set the alpha value